# Microsoft Word 2010 default Save As File Type

Tags: ms-word, file-type

If I open a `.mhtml` file in word, and click the "Save As" option, the default "Save As Type" is `.mhtml`. But I need the default "Save As Type" to be `.doc/.docx`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks leppie, for updated the tags... i missed.

Comment: Is this more super user than stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2):

Create handler for saving event, in this event analyse type of the original document and show your own SaveAs dialog.

Details:

**1. Handler**

In normal template, create a class, for example *clsSaveAs*:

```
Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application

Private Function IsMime(fileName As String)
    Dim mimeTag As String
    'open document
    Open fileName For Input Access Read As #1
    On Error Resume Next
    'read beginning of the document
    Input #1, mimeTag
    On Error GoTo 0
    Close #1
    'MHTM file starts with "MIME" string
    IsMime = Left(mimeTag, 4) = "MIME"
End Function

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforeSave _
 (ByVal Doc As Document, _
 SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
 Cancel As Boolean)

    'get extension
    ar = Split(Doc.Name, ".")
    ext = LCase(ar(UBound(ar)))

    'what is the document MIME type?
    If IsMime(Doc.FullName) Then
        'my own saveas dialog
        With Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
            .Format = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument 'docx
            .Show
        End With
        Cancel = True 'cancel saving process
    Else
        'normal saving
        Cancel = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**2. Using handler**

In normal template create a new module:

```
Dim csa As New clsSaveAs

Sub Register_Event_Save_As_Handler()
    Set csa.appWord = Word.Application
End Sub

'autorun for any opening document
'Note: AutoOpen could be only one in normal template
Sub AutoOpen()
    'could be run only for mht, mhtm documents, but never mind
    Register_Event_Save_As_Handler
End Sub
```

You need have this code in the MHTML document. You could do it this way (but I haven't tried it):

- create a new document in MS Word and save it as normal HTML file
- create in this document a new class (*clsSaveAs*, see above) and in any module the second part of the code
- see at saved document: there is a folder named *_files* and in this folder a file *editdata.mso*; this is the macro; you have to code it in a MHTML file (when you save it as MHTML file, you will see, how it is done)
- in document you have to link this file, look in HTML document and find a row like

Note that all this job is non-standard and you are walking on thin ice, be careful.

Useful links:

- [Using Events with the Application Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821218%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Application.DocumentBeforeSave Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838299%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Roman Plischke, If i am correct, we need to add this in the Normal template file in the MsWord installation path. If so, we need to do this in all the systems we are trying to open this file. Actually, what i need is, i have a file with MHTML contents in it. I saved that file with the extension ".doc". Now, if i open that file in MSword and click on "Save As" option, in the "Save As type" dropdown ".mhtml" is selected by default. But i want is ".doc" has to be selected by default. Is there any way to make this happens, by writing some extra lines in the MHTML file.

Comment: At first: Is it really MHTML file saved with ".doc" extension? In VBA you can recognise type of original document only by extension (or read by VBA contents of the file and analyse it, ok, but it is a torture). Use .mht or .mhtm extension. At second: You can put all the code above in every MHTML file instead of normal template. I you need generate the MSHTML file by another programm than MS Word, it would be possible, but horrible way. In this case, a hint: put by word macro in the document, save as .mht and open in notepad, the macro is coded in Content-Location: file:///.../editdata.mso.

Comment: Yes, it is the MHTML file saved with ".doc" extension. But, i can't save it in .mht or.mhtml format, since the requirement is the need of dynamic word document created programmatically using java. So, we converted MHTML file as ".doc" extension. In this way we can open in MSWord on double click. I hope your second point will help me out. I will take a try on it. As per your comment, we have to place the above two set of codes 1.Handler and 2.Using handler in the first line of MHTML file. Is it correct? Let me show or give some sample MHTML file with this case. It may be helpful for me.

Comment: I have edited my post. I've added code for analysing a document instead extension recognition and some hints for coding it all in MHTML file. Basic idea is, that MHTML is MIME-coded HTML file, so create document, write macro, save as HTML, analyse how it is done and do MHTML by your own way (java in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Office's help documents:

```
1-Click the File tab.
2-Click Options.
3-Click Save.
4-Under Save documents, click "Word 97-2003 Document (*.doc)" or "Word Document (*.docx)" in the Save files in this format.
```

Comment: The steps you mentioned is for saving a new document. But, what i need is i have already saved a MHTML file in the extension as .doc. When i opened that document in word and click on Save As button, the default Save As Type selected is ".mhtml" instead of ".doc".